# How to make frisby.js scripts "pause" during chained executions of apis

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I want to test a session timeout using Frisby.js.  So I want to call our login API and call an API to demonstrate the user is logged in.
Then I want frisby.js to wait 20 minutes for the session to timeout and verify that an further calls fail due to session timeout.  How do I get the frisby.js script to "sleep()"?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that there's an undocumented `waits()` method that effectively tells frisby to sleep.

For example,

```
frisby.create('Sleep test')
  .get('http://www.citibikenyc.com/stations/json')
  .expectStatus(200)
  .inspectJSON()
  .waits(5000)
.toss();
```

Will wait for 5 seconds before execution.

Answer (score 2):

Using setTimeout results in expects not being executed, as explained here:
https://github.com/vlucas/frisby/issues/200

Easiest way I found was to do a .get to http://httpbin.org/delay/3 to delay 3 seconds, then in the .after of this request you do what you wanted to do.

Comment: this works but it's not exactly elegant especially for bigger tests if you need to wait more often

Answer (score -2):

Use a timeout :

```
   setTimeout(function(){
    //do whatever after 20 minutes
   },1200000); //20 min = 1200000ms
```